# How to create an object with functions and data in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am creating an object (a dummy http response object) as illustrated below:

```
res = {
    body : '',
    write : (text : string) => {
        this.body = this.body + text;
    },
    end : () => {}
};
```

But the typescript compiler is giving error:

> error TS2108: 'this' cannot be referenced within module bodies.

I know this is possible (to have `this` inside object) in javascript, how to accomplish this in typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish it by changing the arrow function `write` to standard function, then it will work as usually in plain JavaScript.

```
res = {
    body : '',
    write : function(text: string) {
        this.body = this.body + text;
    },
    end : () => {}
};
```

This is because of how arrow functions change how `this` work within them. It is well described [here](http://piotrwalat.net/arrow-function-expressions-in-typescript/).

> **Standard functions** (ie. written using function keyword) will
>   **dynamically bind this** depending on execution context (just like in
>   JavaScript), **arrow functions** on the other hand will **preserve this of**
>   **enclosing context**. This is a conscious design decision as arrow
>   functions in ECMAScript 6 are meant to address some problems
>   associated with dynamically bound this (eg. using function invocation
>   pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Before David submitted the (correct) answer, I managed to come up with a work-around. It doesn't answer my own question but it is a possible solution.

Create a `class Response`:

```
class Response {
    body : string;
    constructor() {
        this.body = '';
    }
    write(text : string) {
        this.body = this.body + text;
    }
    end() {}
}
```

and then make `res` a object of type `Response`:

```
res = new Response();
```